# Explain: Apache Rewrite, public in URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I realize there are many hits for `public in URL` however I would like an explanation.

**Apache configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    ServerAdmin vagrant@localhost
    DocumentRoot /sites/MVC/public

    <Directory /sites/MVC>
            Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**public/.htaccess:**

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Basically when I try to `print_r()` the url received, it prints public as the first element of the array. The URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/this/that` will result in this output:

```
Array ( [0] => public [1] => this [2] => that )
```

Why is it that public is included in the url when it is not explicitly stated?

**Edit**

P.S. For anyone wondering; the reason `127.0.0.0.1:8080` resolves to port 80 is because it is being hosted via a VM managed by [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/).

`index.php` creates an instance of `App` which breaks up the URL.

**App.php:**

```
class App {

    // Defaults. This will default the app to home/index with 0 parameters
    protected $controller = "home";
    protected $method = "index";
    protected $params = [];


    public function __construct() {
        print_r($this->parseUrl());
    }

    private function parseUrl() {
        if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
            return $url=explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to look at `index.php` and follow through how it breaks up the url. That htaccess will turn `http://127.0.0.1:8080/this/that` into `http://127.0.0.1:8080/index.php?url=this/that`. Something in `index.php` will take the variable `$url` and split it into an array.

Comment: @Styphon I've included the code that breaks up the URL, perhaps you see something I've missed.

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r($_GET['url']);` ?

Comment: @Styphon as I mentioned above, the output of the print_r() is `Array ( [0] => public [1] => this [2] => that )` where the given URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/this/that`. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: but that's after `parseUrl` has run right? I'm asking you to check the raw input straight from `$_GET`.

Comment: I didn't read that correctly, sorry. The output of `print_r($_GET['url'])` is `public/this`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any reason why that would happen. This one is beyond me, sorry. Hopefully someone else with more knowledge will come along and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the `.htaccess` file in the wrong directory, it should have been in the `public/` directory rather than the `/` root directory of the application itself. Very junior mistake I know..

I hope this helps anyone else making such a simple mistake.